# MySQL: how to copy a database from one server to another without export / import

Tags: php, mysql

I have access on two different Windows systems. There is one MySQL database on one system which I want to copy to another system. Please note that I haven't username and password for DB access on the first system where this database available.
I have already searched this this issue and did not found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241102/copy-a-database-with-data-in-mysql) relevant for me.

Comment: I haven't username and password ?

Comment: @Joraid: Read as *don't have*.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439596/copy-data-from-one-server-to-another-using-query-in-import-export-wizard

Comment: yes, I haven't username and password of the database system.

Comment: why you are not going to export/import?

Comment: @GaneshPatil: Without access to DB, how can I perform export and import. Please read the question carefully.

Comment: @Tzar: Correct. I want to copy the database.

Comment: Can you please give more details as to what MySQL you using.. Like using wamp, xampp, or direct install? & if you intend to do this as you've forgotten your password, then there are ways to recover a password.

Comment: @Ravinder thx, now I understand, thought it was a type or something.

Comment: @Tzar: I am using direct install MySQL 5.1 on first system where database reside. The system in which I want to copy is MySQL 5.5 within Wamp.

Comment: The question you linked *is* relevant to you need, please read the answers carefully. If it really isn't, then your question is unclear, please explain carefully why these solutions did not adress your needs. Also, please read the FAQ carefully, this question is off-topic on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

i can help u with

Copy all files from first machine resides in `C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\data`

and copy it to in your new maching in same path.

Hope it helps

Comment: I tried by copied the folder from one system to another. But, it didn't work. I got only list of tables. I can run show tables from dbname. It list the tables. But, when I run select * from dbname.table1 - it shows `Table 'dbname.tablename' doesn't exist`

Comment: for me it worked ! i have tried this many times , I guess there is some problem !! i can suggest you that try to copy only one table first, i guess mysql tables duplicated or conflicted. :(

Answer (score 1):

try this data Migrator

```
<?php 
/**
 * Data Migrator Merger is for merging the data/records of two database of completely same or similar schema.
 * 
 * @author Nitesh Apte
 */

class DataMigratorMreger {

    private $conn;
    private $sourceDB;
    private $destinationDB;


    public function __construct() {
        $this->conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    }

    public function mergeData($oldSchema, $newSchema, $reverse = FALSE) {
        mysql_query("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0");

        if($reverse) {
            $this->destinationDB = $oldSchema;
            $this->sourceDB = $newSchema;
        } else {
            $this->destinationDB = $newSchema;
            $this->sourceDB = $oldSchema;
        }

        mysql_query("use ".$oldSchema);

        $tables = $this->getAssoc("show tables");

        for($i=0;$i<count($tables);$i++) {

            /* Disable this in case you want to merge the data */
            $trun = "TRUNCATE $this->destinationDB.".$tables[$i]['Tables_in_'.$this->sourceDB];
            mysql_query($trun);

            $values = $this->getAssoc("describe ".$tables[$i]['Tables_in_'.$oldSchema]);

            // put $j=1 in case of merging. Generally, first column is auto incremented id
            for($j=0;$j<count($values);$j++) {
                $val[$i][] =  $values[$j]['Field'];
            }

            $field = implode(',', $val[$i]);

            $sql = "INSERT INTO $this->destinationDB.".$tables[$i]['Tables_in_'.$oldSchema]." ($field) SELECT ".$field." FROM $this->sourceDB.".$tables[$i]['Tables_in_'.$oldSchema];

            mysql_query($sql);
        }

        mysql_query("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1");
    }

    public function getAssoc($queryString) {

        $rs = mysql_query($queryString, $this->conn);

        while($rw = @mysql_fetch_array($rs, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
            $values[] = $rw;
        }
        return $values;
    }
}
?>
```